# How to sync Client and server Collection on Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I am trying to sync my server collection with my client collection.

On the Server:

```
var JobLoopUsers = new Meteor.Collection("job-loop-users")

Meteor.publish("user-data", function(){
  JobLoopUsers.findOne({meteorUserId : 1});
});
```

On the Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("user-data");

JobLoopUsers = new Meteor.Collection("job-loop-users");
```

I insert some test data on the server using meteor.call

On the server when I do

```
console.log( JobLoopUsers.find().fetch()[0] )
```

it displays:

```
 {meteorUserId: 1
   testData: "My Test Data Here"}
```

When I do

```
console.log( JobLoopUsers.find().fetch())
```

on the client I just get an empty array.

How do I sync up these two collections?

The Meteor Docs say :

When you subscribe to a record set, it tells the server to send records to the client. The client stores these records in local Minimongo collections, with the same name as the collection argument to set. Meteor will queue incoming attributes until you declare the Meteor.Collection on the client with the matching collection name.

Do I need to do an autosubscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are automatically sync'd in realtime. What might be happening is the data you are inserting doesn't have a `meteorUserId:1` and it is not published to the client, and you're searching for all records whether they have `meteorUserId:1` or not.

To fix this try and alter:

```
Meteor.publish("user-data", function(){
  JobLoopUsers.find({});
});
```

You don't have to do an autosubscribe unless you need a subscription to change for some reason

You may also be calling `console.log( JobLoopUsers.find().fetch())` too soon, try waiting a second or two, replace it with:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function() { console.log( JobLoopUsers.find().fetch()) }, 3000);
```

Comment: Still nothing on the client side.  Maybe I am naming something incorrectly?  I have removed the autopublish package for security.

Comment: updated my answer, perhaps its that the client is async and you're calling the function too soon

Comment: yes, I know for a fact that the problem is that this call <<Meteor.subscribe("user-data");>> is NOT synchronous (despite the fact that it looks synchronous)...which means that the line "JobLoopUsers.find().fetch())" on the client won't return anything until after the subscription is complete. This is a very common problem with Meteor, I hope they find a way around this.

Comment: @AlexMills you can use the callback from Meteor.subscribe i.e `Meteor.subscribe("xxx", function(err) {...})`, or use JobLoopUsers.find().. in a place where reactivity is allowed to make sure something runs when the subscription is complete

Comment: @Akshat, you should add what you just said to your answer, because I believe your answer is wrong/incomplete, but what you just mentioned is correct

Answer (score 1):

Following the tutorial here helped me solve my problem :  http://andrewscala.com/meteor/

It seems to be working.

Global.js:

```
JobLoopUsers = new Meteor.Collection("user-data");
```

Client.js:

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function (){
  Meteor.subscribe("user-data", Meteor.userId())  
})
```

Server.js:

```
Meteor.publish("user-data", function(userId){
  return JobLoopUsers.find({meteorUserId: userId})
})
```